# How to convert wcstombs to wcstombs_s

Tags: c++, visual-c++, deprecated

How can I convert the following code to use wcstombs_s instead of wcstombs?

```
char dbcs[1024];
char *pbstr = (char *)pPropVar->bstrVal;
int i = wcstombs(dbcs, pPropVar->bstrVal, *((DWORD *)(pbstr - 4)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char dbcs[1024];
char *pbstr = (char *)pPropVar->bstrVal;
size_t i;
int err = wcstombs_s(&i, dbcs, 1024, pPropVar->bstrVal, *((DWORD *)(pbstr - 4)));
```

## Note

By the way, you can tell the compiler not to warn about non secure calls:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

Comment: Does not work. It says "function does not take 4 arguments" and also says "no instance of overloaded function "wcstombs_s" matches the argument list........... argument types are: (char [1024], BSTR, DWORD, int)"

Comment: Now this error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'size_t *"